# React Native how to pass prop to Another Screen Without Going to that screen

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

Simple straightforward question, this code is used to pass a prop from a screen to screen and going to that screen, this code works for me:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('RouteName', { refresh: yes })
```

But this code NAVIGATES me to that screen too. I want to pass prop to a screen but without going to that screen. How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, if you use **navigation.navigate** function it means you are navigating to next screen and passing props as a parameter to use in another screen.

But if you just want to store the data for future use without navigating to the different screen then you can use **async-storage** to save the data and use it whenever you want

Example

import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

**Storing data**

```
const storeData = async (value) => {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('refresh', "yes")
  } catch (e) {
    // saving error
  }
}
```

**Reading data**

```
const getData = async () => {
  try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('refresh')
    if(value !== null) {
      // value previously stored
    }
  } catch(e) {
    // error reading value
  }
}
```

By using async-storage you can access the values from any screen. you can even use redux also.

If you use async-storage make sure you install the dependency.

***I hope this will be helpful. Goodluck!***

Comment: Thank u this is what I need. I just have a question, in the reading data inside if how would I console log the item value in our case called refresh. ? Is it console.log(value)? Is it console.log(refresh) is it console. Log(item)?

Comment: When you run the getData function the value will be saved in const like this ** const refresh = await AsyncStorage.getItem('refresh') ** then you can do console.log(refresh) to use the value.